# iPhone OpenGL-ES : UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, touch

Do UISwipeGestureRecognizer work in OpenGL.  I know its a odd thing to ask but I have just added them to my project like I have to other projects and well its not working.  Its not firing the events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can add a gesture recognizer to any view. The view does not care if it's OpenGL or something else that's being rendered in it.

Comment: I did  try but it's not firing off the selector

Comment: Do you have userInteractionEnabled set to YES on the relevant view?